# $I$ injective $A$-module, $\phi:A\to B\implies \text{Hom}_A(B,I)$ injective $B$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, injective-module

> Let $A,B$ be commutative rings with unit, $\phi:A\to B$ a ring homomorphism and $I$ an injective $A$-module. Prove that $\text{Hom}_A(B,I)$ is an injective $B$-module.

Here is my attempt:

Let $M,N$ be $B$-modules, $g:M\to\text{Hom}_A(B,I)$ and $f:M\to N$ with $\ker f=0$. Our goal is to construct $h:N\to\text{Hom}_A(B,I)$ with $h\circ f=g$.

Let $\phi^*:B\text{-Mod}\to A\text{-Mod}$ be the functor of restriction of scalars (notation: $X^*:=\phi^*(X)$ for any object or morphism $X$ in $B$-Mod).

That way, we get $f^*:M^*\to N^*$ with $\ker f^*=0$ and, for $b\in B$, we may define $g_b:M^*\to I$ with $g_b(m)=g(m)(b)$. Since $I$ is injective, there exists $h_b:N^*\to I$ with $h_b\circ f^*=g_b$.

What I want to do is to define $h:N\to\text{Hom}_A(B,I)$ as $h(n)(b)=h_b(n)$. But in order to $h$ be well-defined, I'd have to show that $h_{b+c}(n)=h_b(n)+h_c(n)$, which I still can't figure out.

Is it possible? How? If not, how to I approach this problem?

Comment: I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction#General_Statement) solves your highlighted question immediately.

Comment: @user26857, thanks, that's a very elegant solution. I'm still curious whether or not we can prove prove $h_{b+c}(n)=h_b(n)+h_c(n)$, which is my attempt. What do you think?

Comment: I can't confirm this with a counterexample, but I suspect your method won't work. There's no uniqueness condition on the map $h_b$ that you get from $g_b$ by injectivity, and it seems plausible that you could choose the $h_b$'s poorly/incompatibly due to this lack of uniqueness (and then wind up with $h_{b + c}\neq h_b + h_c$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of $B$-module on $\operatorname{Hom}_A(B,I)$ is defined by
$$
bh\colon x\mapsto h(bx)
$$
for $h\colon B\to I$. In particular, $bh(1)=h(b)$.

You can use Baer’s criterion. Suppose $\mathfrak{b}$ is an ideal of $B$ and you are given $f\colon\mathfrak{b}\to\operatorname{Hom}_A(B,I)$.

Define $\hat{f}\colon\mathfrak{b}\to I$ by $\hat{f}(b)=f(b)(1)$, which is a homomorphism of $A$-modules. This extends to a homomorphism of $A$-modules $g\colon B\to I$, since $I$ is injective.

Now we can show that $f(b)=bg$. Indeed, for $x\in B$,
$$
bg(x)=g(bx)=f(bx)(1)=(xf(b))(1)=f(b)(x)
$$
because $f$ is $B$-linear.